# Spring boot validation annotations @Valid and @NotBlank not working

Tags: java, validation, spring-boot, soapui

Given below is my main controller from which I am calling the **getPDFDetails** method.

```
@RequestMapping(value=PATH_PRINT_CONTRACTS, method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> printContracts(@RequestBody final UpdatePrintContracts updatePrintContracts) throws Exception {
    
        System.out.println("contracts value is "+ updatePrintContracts);
        
        Integer cancellationReasons = service.getPDFDetails(updatePrintContracts);
        
        System.out.println("success!");
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok(cancellationReasons);
    }
```

Below is the **UpdatePrintContracts** class where I have defined all the variables with validation annotations and corresponding getter/setter methods.

```
public class UpdatePrintContracts {
    
    @Valid
    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = "\\p{Alnum}{1,30}")
    String isReprint;
    
    @Valid
    @NotBlank
    Integer dealerId;
    
    @Valid
    @NotBlank
    @Pattern(regexp = "\\p{Alnum}{1,30}")
    String includeSignatureCoordinates;
    
    @Valid
    @NotBlank
    java.util.List<Integer> contractNumbers;

    public String getIsReprint() {
        return isReprint;
    }

    public void setIsReprint(String isReprint) {
        this.isReprint = isReprint;
    }

    public Integer getDealerId() {
        return dealerId;
    }

    public void setDealerId(Integer dealerId) {
        this.dealerId = dealerId;
    }

    public String getIncludeSignatureCoordinates() {
        return includeSignatureCoordinates;
    }

    public void setIncludeSignatureCoordinates(String includeSignatureCoordinates) {
        this.includeSignatureCoordinates = includeSignatureCoordinates;
    }

    public java.util.List<Integer> getContractNumbers() {
        return contractNumbers;
    }

    public void setContractNumbers(java.util.List<Integer> contractNumbers) {
        this.contractNumbers = contractNumbers;
    }
    
}
```

I am trying to run the application as a Spring Boot app by right clicking on the project (Run As) and passing blank values for variables **isReprint** and **includeSignatureCoordinates** through Soap UI. However the validation doesn't seem to work and is not throwing any validation error in Soap UI. What am I missing? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `@NotBlank` is for text only, not integer. Try to start from the simplest, with only one field for validation like `@NotBlank String foo;` if that works, move on to other more complicated ones like `@Pattern`

Comment: In my case I forgot to add @Valid tag in Controller

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First you dont need to have @Valid annotation for those class variables in UpdatePrintContracts . You can delete them.

To trigger validation of a @Controller input, simply annotate the input argument as @Valid or @Validated:

```
@RequestMapping(value=PATH_PRINT_CONTRACTS, method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> printContracts(@Valid @RequestBody  final UpdatePrintContracts updatePrintContracts) throws Exception {
```

[Refer here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/) for full understanding of validating models in spring boot.

And If you want to check that a string contains only specific characters, you must add anchors (^ for beginning of the string, $ for end of the string) to be sure that your pattern matches all the string.Curly brackets are only to write a quantity,

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[\\p{Alnum}]{1,32}$")
```

Lastly i assume you have following jars in your classpath,

.validation-api.jar (contains the abstract API and the annotation scanner)

.hibernate-validator.jar (contains the concrete implementation)

Comment: try not sending isReprint /includeSignatureCoordinates , and see if you get error.Note that not sending and sending blank are 2 different thing, i hope you know what i mean

Comment: Wouldn't a @validated notation above class declaration achieve the same end?

Answer (score 134):

If you are facing this problem in latest version of spring boot (2.3.0) make sure to add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Observation:**
In earlier version of Spring Boot (1.4.7), `javax.validation` used to work out of the box. But, after upgrading to latest version, annotations broke. Adding the following dependency alone doesn't work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Because this provides JSR Specification but not the implementation. You can also use `hibernate-validator` instead of `spring-boot-starter-validation`.

Comment: Adding the spring-boot-starter-validation solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: this is the solution for me. Is there a way to give less information about validation error, I mean traces message contions inner code flow

Comment: This solved my problem !! I am using Spring Boot v2.6

Answer (score 37):

For Anyone who is getting this issue with **2.0.1.Final**:

In all SpringBoot versions above 2.2, **Validations starter is not a part of web starter anymore**

[Check Notes here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#validation-starter-no-longer-included-in-web-starters)

So, all you have to do is add this dependency in your build.gradle/pom file

GRADLE:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
```

MAVEN

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am using `web-starter-2.6.5` apparently no proper validation of `@NotNull`, `@NotEmpty`, and `@NotBlank` there but there is `@NonNull` and `Validated` from `org.springframework.lang`. I was confused a while and verified `@NonNull` and `Validated` are NOT the proper validation to use. Thanks for the answer it helped.

Answer (score 24):

I faced the same error.

I had to use the below 2 dependencies alone:

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

And use `@Validated` annotation(import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated) on rest controller level and `@Valid` annotation at method argument level(import javax.validation.Valid)

If there are any other extra dependencies like `javax.validation.validation-api`, `org.hibernate.hibernate-validator`, etc then the validations stopped working for me. So make sure that you remove these dependencies from pom.xml

Comment: Works. Docs don't mention this at all.Like we are just supposed to know these things.

Comment: This comment saved me from the debugging hell that I was going through only because I had the `javax.validation.validation-api` and the `org.hibernate.hibernate-validator` as dependencies. By doing the other steps (having the `spring-boot-starter-validation`, the @Validated and @Valid annotations) everything magically worked! Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Same problem here, I tried everything, but it only worked after removing the org.hibernate.hibernate-validator from the classpath

Comment: For me there is no need for `@Validated annotation(import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated)`

Answer (score 12):

Make sure to use @Valid annotation before @RequestBody

For newer versions of spring boot ensure all validation annotation are picked from `jakarta.validation.*` package and not `javax.validation.*`. As the annotations are named same in both.

Comment: I'm using spring boot 3 and hibernate-validator 8.0.0.Final and importing `jakarta.validation.*` instead of `javax.validation.*` annotations is what solved my problem.

Comment: @Adarsh R Jayan perfect answer this is the only solution that is working remember to add `@Validated` in the Controller and also use jakarta import for `@Valid` in the controller

Answer (score 10):

I was using This dependency of validation in spring boot and didn't work ,

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
<artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
<version>2.0.1.Final</version>
```

I replaced it with spring-boot-starter-validation and it worked .

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot- 
starter-validation -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
<version>2.4.0</version>
```

Comment: also please add in the code @Validated where the request body to be validated in the rest controller

Comment: This was the problem for me. After changing the dependencies as mentioned above, it worked.

Answer (score 8):

this is for anyone here who still has the same issue after following the steps mentioned above. I had to restart my IDE (IntelliJ) for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using spring version > 3

and using Kotlin you should add @field:Annotation

ex:

```
@field:NotEmpty
@field:NotNull
@field:NotBlank(message = "Email is required")
@field:Email(message = "Please provide a valid email")
val email: String,
@field:NotEmpty
@field:NotNull
@field:NotBlank(message = "Password is required")
val password: String,
```

Comment: The question is tagged "java" (and **not** "kotlin") so I don't know how much posting Kotlin code will help.

Comment: Thanks! I was having the same issue but with Kotlin and your comment about `@field:Annotation` helped

Comment: Thanks! Although this is not purely java, it can be difficult to find kotlin quirks. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 5):

My problem solved by this.
When we use classes inside classes that also need validations so `@Valid` needs to be annotated to all in that case.
[Link for more details](https://medium.com/javarevisited/are-you-using-valid-and-validated-annotations-wrong-b4a35ac1bca4)

Answer (score 4):

**Step-1: Add these two dependency in the pom.xml file**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**Step-2: Create a Custom Exception class like this**

```
package com.bjit.salon.auth.service.exceptions;


import org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@ControllerAdvice
public class AnynameApplicationException {

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<List<String>> processUnmergeException(final 
MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {

        List<String> list = ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().stream()
                .map(DefaultMessageSourceResolvable::getDefaultMessage)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(list, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

**Step-3: Add @Valid annotation to the method arguments like this way**

```
public ResponseEntity<?> registerAccount(@Valid @RequestBody UserRegisterDto 
      registerDto) {
       
    // rest of the codes
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone like me using spring boot 3.X.

After the jackarta update you have to include extra config in order for the request body validation to work. (The field validation was working just fine even without extra config)

At the end all I needed was

```
@Configuration
public class ValidationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

and     `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'`

it is recommended to use the spring boot maven/gradle plugin so there are no version discrepencies

Comment: I didn't have to add a `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` like you did, the only change I needed was annotating the Controller with the new `@Validated` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

- This answer is in

  ## **kotlin**

  you can also refer this for java syntext is highly similar
- Create a exception handler
- **Tip**: check console for exception class
  to log error message in console add this line to **application.properties**

```kotlin
server.error.include-message =  always
```

```kotlin
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError
import org.springframework.validation.ObjectError
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus
import java.util.function.Consumer

@ControllerAdvice
class MethodArgumentNotValidExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException::class)
    @ResponseBody
    fun handleValidationExceptions(ex: MethodArgumentNotValidException): ResponseEntity<Map<String, String?>> {
        val errors: MutableMap<String, String?> = HashMap()
        ex.bindingResult.allErrors.forEach(Consumer { error: ObjectError ->
            val fieldName = (error as FieldError).field
            val errorMessage = error.getDefaultMessage()
            errors[fieldName] = errorMessage
        })
        println(errors)
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errors)
    }
}
```

- use jakarta validation instead of java x in am using spring 3+

```
    implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
```

- if your are using kotlin target annotation to fields

```kotlin
import jakarta.persistence.*
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Email
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Pattern
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails

@Entity
@Table(name = "_user")
data class User(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Int? = null,
    @field:NotBlank var firstName: String = "",
    @field:NotBlank var lastName: String = "",
    @field:Email @Column(unique = true) var email: String = "",
    @field:Column(unique = true, name = "password")
    @field:NotBlank private var _password: String = "",
)
```

- in your router class use @Validated annotation

```
import jakarta.validation.Valid
```

```kotlin
    @PostMapping("/login")
    fun login(
        @Validated @RequestBody reqBody: User,
    ): ResponseEntity<String>? {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(
            accountService.login(
                email = reqBody.email,
                password = reqBody.password
            ).bind()
        )
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Note:** SNAPSHOT, M1, M2, M3, and M4 releases typically WORK IN PROGRESS. The Spring team is still working on them, Recommend NOT using them.

Answer (score 1):

Add this dependency to your **pom.xml** file and **@NotBlank, @NotNull, @Valid**, etc. should work fine.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with entities in my Kotlin Spring boot 3.x application.
Solved by adding `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency and adding anotation `@field:NotBlank` (or `@field:NotNull`, `@field:NotEmpty`) on fields.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem
For me adding:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

under the spring-boot-starter-web dependency solved problem.
To be sure you should generate dependency directly with Validation form start spring io. It's worth mentioning that **order of dependencies in pom file is crucial**

Comment: While it is true that dependencies order is fundamental, what was your issue? Shading? Wrong version?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using wrong maven repository
I was using

```
javax.validation
```

this library is depricated and repostiroy moved to

```
jakarta.validation-api
```

so update you pom.xml with this

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.validation/jakarta.validation-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use @NotEmpty will check for both blank and null values.
Add @Valid to your RestContoller class methods